# Need Thin Table Borders in PDF Generated by cfDocument

Tags: css, pdf, coldfusion

I'm using border-collapse (CSS) to make thin borders on my table.  They render fine on the screen, but when they are sent into a PDF, via cfDocument, they end up as thicker grey borders.

I read that cfDocument doesn't support border-collapse yet, so what's my best option?

ColdFusion 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables are so 90's but this does seem to work for cfdocument pdf (inconsistent on web browser display though):

```
.tbl {background-color:#000;}
.tbl td,th,caption{background-color:#fff}
```

...

```
<table cellspacing="1" class="tbl">
...
</table>
```

(border-spacing in style setting doesn't work - you have to put the attr in the table tag)

Comment: Well, this is the best answer so far.  It actually does give me the thin lines I want.  It's the only solution that did that.

Comment: However, it's not perfect, because you have to manually specify the _cellspacing_ attribute in the _table_ tag.  This keeps you from having a zero _cellspacing_ for your screen display and being able to control print vs screen styles.  This is not optimal, but at least we found a way to get the thin lines.

Comment: How in the wide, wide world of sports are tables "so 90s"?

How do you expect to lay out tabular data without tables?

Comment: I was in an environment where everyone was switching to divs. When I said I LIKE tables, they laughed. That was a bit before 2010. I still use tables. A lot :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue with borders in cfdocument.  Here are some tricks I learned:

Rather than setting your CSS like this:

```
table td {
  border: solid thin black;
}
```

Try this:

```
table, table td {
  border: solid black;
}
table {
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
}
table td {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
```

This explicitly makes the width as small as possible.  Also, it avoids the problem of "doubling" the widths that would occur due to each cell having their own 1px border and then having them sit adjacent to each other (so between the cells, you would in effect have a 2px border).

Also, you can reduce your "scale" value to the cfdocument tag to reduce the size of everything, including the thickness of your borders.

Comment: This is actually a technique I used to do, but abandoned it when I discovered _border-collapse_ because it creates small gaps at the border junctions.  But that may be better than the thick lines I'm currently getting. Thanks!

Comment: Well... I tried this and it didn't thin the lines any more than when they were formatted to collapse.  Dangit.

Comment: Did you try adjusting the scale?

Answer (score 2):

cfdocument has many limitations. if you're looking for css3 support, javascript etc I recommend [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). It uses webkit to generate the PDF so it supports most of what Safari/Chrome supports.

Comment: I'm using wkhtmltopdf and struggling with exactly the same issue :)

Answer (score 2):

I decided to see if CFDOCUMENT would understand old-school HTML since the solution above varied by browser. It's not ideal, but if you need to make it work, this might help:

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="black">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="white">Data</td>
        <td bgcolor="white">Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="white">Data</td>
        <td bgcolor="white">Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="white">Data</td>
        <td bgcolor="white">Data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as the accepted one, by Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend report builder, it will give you fine grain pixel level control and paging.

Comment: report builder might bring another set of challenges though. ;)

Comment: report builder is truly awful! It's buggy as hell and requires learning a new layout/template paradigm.

Answer (score -1):

Report builder is only useful when you want to quickly create an interactive tabular type report that allows the user to UN-collapse a row to get more data details that would be child to the parent row of focus.

I have to say I found this pretty useful and very close to what SSRS offers. But doesn't really help when it comes to exporting to pdf or excel.

Answer (score -1):

```
border-bottom: 0.4pt solid #ccc;
```